# Is there an alternative to use marshalling/unmarshalling?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have been working on a small app, where I need to respond with XML messages like

```
<response>
<message>blah</message>
</response>
```

I find marshalling very confusing, is there a better way or alternative to this approach?

EDIT: My question was to gain a little insight into what is better? Using marshaling/unmarshaling or some easier alternatives to that approach.

Comment: Which environment are you working in? Android? Objective-C? VB.net?

Comment: @FrankPl I'm working on Java

Comment: Consider using JAXB, here there is a very good tutorial > http://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/

Comment: @guisantogui, thanks.. I'll look at the tutorial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an alternative, you can hardcode the xml tags in your output message, and add your messagge (blah) between those tags. It wouldn't be too complicated for a small message like this. Like

```
System.out.println("<response><message>" +
            yourMessageHere + "</message></response>");
```

But, in case of a longer complicated message, you could very easily complicate the ordering of tags or forget to type something and it could get even frustrating.

I'd suggest trying marshalling/unmarshalling. I did it for one of my assignments, I agree it looks complicated when you start but once you get hang of it, you don't have to worry about well-formedness of your XML.

Comment: Thanks for your response.. Right now, my messages are pretty small, like the one I posted. I guess I could hard code. I am using this for a school assignment, and don't want to put more time/effort than needed at this point.

Comment: What happens with `String yourMessageHere = "Just to mess things up I'm going to type </message>"`? For a school assignment it probably doesn't matter, but it's important in production code. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection for a variant of this problem.

Comment: I agree, I would suggest when you get some time in future, you should explore into JAXB.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll definitely look into it..

Answer (score 2):

For really simple documents you can use the StAX APIs instead of building an XML `String`.  This makes it much more difficult to introduce errors.

**Demo Code**

Below are the StAX calls necessary to produce the XML from your question.  Just to make things interesting the message contains a character that is not valid in the XML document.

```
import javax.xml.stream.*;

public class StAXDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        XMLOutputFactory xof = XMLOutputFactory.newFactory();
        XMLStreamWriter xsw = xof.createXMLStreamWriter(System.out);

        xsw.writeStartDocument();
        xsw.writeStartElement("response");
        xsw.writeStartElement("message");
        xsw.writeCharacters("1 < 2");
        xsw.writeEndDocument();

        xsw.close();
    }

}
```

**Output**

We see in the output that the `<` character is properly escaped as `&lt;`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?><response><message>1 &lt; 2</message></response>
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [definition of marshalling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marshalling_(computer_science)) - whatever you do to produce that XML, you are marshalling the data it describes!

The real question is how to go about implementing that marshalling.

In this very simple case, you could hand roll your own Marshaller for that specific data - it could be as simple as hard coding the tags and just filling in the message, as already suggested by @BeginnerJava

```
public class XmlMarshaller {

    public String marshal(String message) {
         return "<response><message>" + message + "</message></response>";
    }
}
```

Then, as suggested by @yshavit, you might want to make sure the message contains no extra xml tags which could break the output.

Then you might want additional features x, y and z, and for the marshaller to simultaneously juggle elephants and bowling balls for a while before returning your xml.

Here's an anthropomorphic visualisation of your marshaller at this point

[image: marshaller with loads of complicated behaviour]

Doesn't look easy, does it?

The point is, for anything but the most simple, narrow marshalling functionality, the short term pain of ramping up on a 3rd party framework like JAXB is going to be *astoundingly* less than the long term pain of writing, enhancing and maintaining your own implementation.

So, when you move beyond school assignments and start building more complex apps, seriously consider investing the time to learn existing frameworks and libraries for common tasks - such as JAXB for marshalling. This approach will make both your code and your productivity far better in the long run :-)

Comment: thanks for the interesting explanation.. I am convinced to look into it in future

Answer (score 0):

[**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) is pretty easy to use.  I will demonstrate below with an example.

### Domain Model

JAXB doesn't require any annotations (see: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/07/jaxb-no-annotations-required.html), but including a root element makes things a bit easier.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Response {

    private String message;

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

}
```

### Demo Code

**Demo**

Below is all you need to do to produce the XML message.  Just for fun I'm going to use a message that would break the [code given by BeginnerJava](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18665432/383861).

```
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Response.class);

        Response response = new Response();
        response.setMessage("1 < 2");

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(response, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

In the output we see that the `<` character has been properly escaped as `&lt;`.  What's harder to see is that the XML output has been marshalled to the correct encoding.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<response>
    <message>1 &lt; 2</message>
</response>
```